# What attributes does Laplace Smoothing apply on in Naive Bayes

Tags: probability, naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

Consider the dataset:

| Outlook | Temperature | Humidity | Play Golf? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Overcast | Cool | Low | Yes |
| Sunny | Hot | Low | Yes |
| Rainy | Cool | High | No |
| Sunny | Hot | High | No |
| Rainy | Cool | Low | Yes |

There are 3 possible values for the feature "Outlook":

- Overcast
- Sunny
- Rainy

P(Yes) = 3/5 and P(No) = 2/5.

The probability of Overcast given No is P(Overcast | No) = 0. I do know to solve this issue, we use Laplace Smoothing with the formula, α/(N + α⋅k). In this case if *α* = 1, 0 + 1/(2 + 1⋅k). What I'm unsure about is what does *k* here means.

So my questions are:

1. Does *k* refer to the number of features (Outlook, Temperature, Humidity) or the number of possible values for Outlook?
2. Do we apply Laplace Smoothing for the feature Outlook or to all other features too?
3. Do we normally check if conditional probability is 0 before applying Laplace Smoothing or do we just apply it straight?

Answer (score 1):

$k$ refers to the possible values for Outlook, because you'll need the sum of all Outlook probabilities be $1$. It's up to you to apply this to all features or not. The smoothing is useful for remedying zero probability cases, but it's also for applying regularization. The degree/strength of regularization depends on the value of $\alpha$ and can be chosen by validation. So, zero probability is not the sole driver behind it.